# How to mock Bundle method in Android Unit-Test?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I have one controller class that handle Fragment creation. Let's say like below:

```
public class FragmentController {

    public static Fragment newInstance(String title, int total) {
        return total > 0? MultipleDataFragment.newInstance(title, total)
            : SingleDataFragment.newInstance(title);
    }
}
```

```
public class MultipleDataFragment extends Fragment {
    public static MultipleDataFragment newInstance( String title, int total) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("title", title);
        b.putInt("total", total);
    }
}
```

```
public class SingleDataFragment extends Fragment {
    public static SingleDataFragment newInstance( String title, int total) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("title", title);
        b.putInt("total", total);
    }
}
```

In my test (standard Junit4 test class) I have:

```
@Test
public void testNewInstanceCreteMultipleData() throws Exception {
    Fragment f = FragmentController.newInstance("Hello", 5);

    assertTrue("MultipleDataFragment should be created"
        , f instanceOf MultipleDataFragment);
}
```

Since I didn't mock the Bundle, I'm getting.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putString not mocked.Set
```

The question is how do I mock the Bundle object so the test can be executed? Do I need static method inside each class that create Bundle object and use that instead or is there a better approach to this?

Any example to this is appreciated.

Comment: Note that your getInstance() methods are incomplete. They do not even have return statements.

Answer (score 6):

One way could be to use a powerful mocking framework like [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), which can even intercept the construction of new objects.

This should work for you but mocking "simple" classes like Bundle means some effort - you could also use the real implementation by using the [UnMock plugin](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin).

Comment: For an example of a mock of the Bundle class, you might want to check out [my answer for very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38700186/976883). Regarding UnMock, I had trouble using it with Bundle as I got a `NoSuchFieldError` for `mMap` while running a simplified test case.

Comment: Starting in API 21, Bundle extends BaseBundle, which is why it can't find mMap. Unfortunately unmocking BaseBundle doesn't help because ArrayMap now uses a non-standard version of System.arraycopy() that the JVM doesn't contain. So unmocking Bundle doesn't work.

Comment: @ErikBrowne what's your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Unmock plugin](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin) to un-mock the Bundle class. You'll need to un-mock with Android 4.4 (`unmock 'org.robolectric:android-all:4.4_r1-robolectric-1'`) since later versions of Android reference non-standard Java methods.

You'll also need to keep ArrayMap and MapCollections.