# How to create a new Bundle object?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use Firebase Analytics for an Android application, and in order to log events I've followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events. That is, in order to send my event, I have to create a new Bundle object (which I create by using the default constructor) and I call the logEvent function of Firebase Analytics. While testing my development with a simple unit test, I realized that there's no content set in the bundle, which makes me wonder if any information is sent at all. Incidentally, it also breaks my test case.

Here's a simplified test case that shows my problem:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("eventType", "click");
        params.putLong("eventId",new Long(5542));
        params.putLong("quantity", new Long(5));
        params.putString("currency", "USD");

        assertEquals("Did not find eventType=click in bundle", "click", params.getString("eventType"));
    }
}
```

This test case fails with the following message:

> junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Did not find eventType=click in bundle
>   Expected :click
>   Actual   :null

Would someone know where the problem is? That is, how do I create a Bundle object from zero and populate it correctly so that I can use it in a unit test like this?

Please bear with me on this one as I'm discovering the specifics of the Android environment as we speak.

Comment: By default you cannot use `Bundle` or any other Android framework classes in your unit tests because the android.jar used for running unit tests contains no code. You should be getting a `RuntimeException` when running these tests. Are you using a mocking framework of any sort to circumvent this?

Comment: Yes, in the complete test case, I'm using Mockito to mock the `Application`  and PowerMockito for the `FirebaseAnalytics` instances. That being said, I still experience the same behaviour as for my simplified test case above, which contains no mocking tools. While running my test in Android Studio, I see no exceptions as the android.jar is on my classpath. Would I need to mock the `Bundle` class too? If so, why and how?

Comment: Yes, you would need to mock Bundle too, which is the main problem here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660507/how-to-mock-bundle-method-in-android-unit-test

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tanis.7x. I've added an answer below; please let me know if this isn't the approach you had in mind.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto, thanks for the link. For the future, it would be nice if you could add a description of your link and not only the link by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by **Tanis.7x** in a comment to my original question, all Android framework classes need to be mocked as the android.jar used for running unit tests is empty as documented [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-).

Here's an updated version of my original simplified test case:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bundle bundleMock = Mockito.mock(Bundle.class);
        Mockito.doReturn("click").when(bundleMock).getString("eventType");
        Mockito.doReturn(new Long(5542)).when(bundleMock).getLong("eventId");
        Mockito.doReturn(new Long(5)).when(bundleMock).getLong("quantity");
        Mockito.doReturn("USD").when(bundleMock).getString("currency");

        assertEquals("Did not find eventType=click in bundle", "click", bundleMock.getString("eventType"));
    }
}
```

The main difference is, that the variables I set earlier with simple getters are now set by using the appropriate functions of Mockito. The code is not as easy on the eyes, but it should allow me to obtain the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `.equals()` to compare strings as `assertEquals()` also uses the  `.equal()` method for its working.

Comment: As you can see from the answer to my question, the problem at hand is clearly not the use of `assertEquals()`, but how to correctly use the Android framework classes.