# Bundle put and get Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to make a test that will verify that a value is successfully written on a `Bundle`.

This is a simple class that will write a boolean value on a `Bundle`:

```
public class Coder {
    public void serialize(Bundle bundle, String key, boolean value) {
        bundle.putBoolean(key, value);
    }
}
```

I want to test the `serialize` method checking the `Bundle` passed as parameter after the method call using `bundle.getBoolean(String)`.

I tried with an `ArgumentCaptor` without success:

```
Coder coder = mock(Coder.class);
Bundle bundle = mock(Bundle.class);

ArgumentCaptor<Bundle> bundleCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Bundle.class);
coder.serialize(bundle, key, expectedValue);
verify(coder).serialize(bundleCaptor.capture(), eq(key), eq(expectedValue));

Bundle mockBundle = bundleCaptor.getValue();
assertEquals(expectedValue, mockBundle.getBoolean(key));
```

But `mockBundle.getBoolean(key)` returns `false`.

If I try to not mock the `Bundle`, I get this exception at `mockBundle.getBoolean(key)`:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getBoolean in android.os.BaseBundle not mocked.`

Comment: Why are you making it so complicated? `Bundle mockBundle = new Bundle()`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I can't because when I have to do `mockBundle.getBoolean(key)` the method `getBoolean(key)` is not mocked

Comment: why does getBoolean() have to be mocked? Don't you want the **actual** value from the bundle?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want the actual value, as you said. I updated the question with the Exception that I'm getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make this overly complicated.

```
public class TestCoder {
    @Test
    public void testSerialize() {
        Coder coder = new Coder();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        coder.serialize(bundle);
        assertEquals(expectedValue, bundle.getBoolean(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your example but I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putBoolean in android.os.BaseBundle not mocked`.

Comment: @Fondesa how do you run the test? Are you doing unit tests or instrumented tests?

Comment: I'm running Unit tests

Comment: @Fondesa what happens if you run it instrumented. Not an ideal solution, I know. Just wondering and it can be a stop gap for now.

Comment: It works with instrumented. I would like to know if it's impossible to get it to work in Unit tests or no. In case I'll switch to instrumented.

Comment: @Fondesa I am not very familiar with unit tests and mocking. You will need to find a way to mock getBoolean() so that it returns the value given by putBoolean().

Comment: At the end, I moved it to instrumented tests.

Comment: @Fondesa perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660507/how-to-mock-bundle-method-in-android-unit-test will help.